# What is the difference between odoo snippets v8 and v9

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8, code-snippets, odoo-9

I want to upgrade to odoo 9, I am still new in odd web development.

the xpath in my snippets is :

```
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='tab-content']" position="inside">
```

It's stays the same or do I add

```
    //div[@id='snippet_content']
```

before the div class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In odoo9 I use:

```
<xpath expr="//div[@id='snippet_structure']/div[@class='o_panel_body']" position="inside">
```